# insert multi table rows in to database by laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

i need to insert a lot of one row in to database any one can help me
this the code

```
$commitee = Committee::create($request->all());
    $now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $data = [
        [
            'committee_id' => $commitee->id, 'user_id' => $request->input('manager'), 'member_type_id' => 1, 'created_by_user_id' => $request->user()->user_id, 'created_at' => $now,
            'updated_at' => $now
        ],
        [
            'committee_id' => $commitee->id, 'user_id' => $request->input('vice'), 'member_type_id' => 2, 'created_by_user_id' => $request->user()->user_id, 'created_at' => $now,
            'updated_at' => $now
        ]

    ];
```

$input = Input::all();
        foreach ($input as $member)
        {
            $items = new CommitteeMember([
            'committee_id' => $committee->id,
            'user_id' => $member['members'],
            'member_type_id' => 3,
            'created_by_user_id' =>$now,
            'updated_at' => $now,
            ]);
            $items->saveMany();
        }

```
    CommitteeMember::insert($data);

<select name="members" id="committee_members" class="input-group-prepend select2">             
                <option value="0">اختر</option>
                @foreach($employees as $key => $name)
                    <option value="{{ $name->user_id }}">{{ $name->user_name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <select name=""  id="" hidden>
                <option value="3" hidden>رئيس</option>
            </select>
```

// image
[only the third table has multi rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQBli.png)`

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to `Committee::insert($data);`

Comment: sorry i alrady edit the code, but i need to insert the third table which in the image..